# How can I get the variable list and their value using azure connection string?

Tags: azure, shell, connection-string, azure-configuration, azure-connect

I have a azure connection string `Endpoint=https://******.azconfig.io;Id=******;Secret=******`.

I would like to fetch and print (write in a file) all the variables using above string. Is there an API/ way to acheive this?

I looked for many solution. could not find anythingg.

Comment: What do you mean by variables?

Answer (score 0):

To get key-values from App Configuration store via `REST API`, you can check below steps:

- Register one Azure AD application and grant **API permissions** for the `Azure App Configuration` API as below:

[image]

- Now, generate bearer token using delegated flows like authorization code flow, username password etc…

I have taken references from the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/rest-api-key-value#list-key-values) - Azure App Configuration REST API - key-value.

- In my case, I have used username password flow to generate bearer token via Postman like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token
grant_type:password
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
resource: https://azconfig.io
username: user1@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password: xxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, use this token to call below REST API:

```http
GET https://<appconfig_name>.azconfig.io/kv/?&api-version=1.0
Authorization: Bearer <token_from_above_Step>
```

**Response:**

[image]

***Using the Azure CLI command.***

I have taken reference from the  [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appconfig/kv?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appconfig-kv-list-examples)  to retrieve the list.

```cs
 az appconfig kv list --endpoint Endpoint="https://sriapp.azconfig.io;Id=E6eW;Secret=**********=" --auth-mode key --name sriapp
```

***Output:***

[image]