# Getting incorrect padding error when connecting to AzureAppConfigurationClient

Tags: python, azure

I am using the following code to get the keyvault value but on running the code i am getting the error
raise binascii.Error("Connection string secret has incorrect padding")
binascii.Error: Connection string secret has incorrect padding

```
from azure.appconfiguration import AzureAppConfigurationClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential. I have updated the latest package as well.
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient


app_string_url = "Endpoint=https://xxx.azconfig.io;Id=123;Secret=123" # not used
secret_name = 'ACS_ENDPOINT'

# Create an instance of AzureAppConfigurationClient
credential=DefaultAzureCredential()

app_config_client = AzureAppConfigurationClient.from_connection_string(connection_string=app_string_url)

    
config_setting = app_config_client.get_configuration_setting(secret_name)

# error at last line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to do the same and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/appconfiguration-readme?view=azure-python):

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.appconfiguration import AzureAppConfigurationClient

tenant_id1 = "83331f4e"
client_id1 = "5461f88"
client_secret1 = "jXI8Q"
app_config_endpoint = "https://apptest.azconfig.io"

secret_key1 = "secret name"
rithcreds = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id1, client_id1, client_secret1)
app_configuration_client = AzureAppConfigurationClient(app_config_endpoint, rithcreds)
secret_value = app_configuration_client.get_configuration_setting(secret_key1).value
print(secret_value)
```

Alternatively you can follow this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446756/how-can-i-get-the-variable-list-and-their-value-using-azure-connection-string)  to get secrets.